# How to convert a string list of unquoted string entries to a list in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a bizzare problem where I am reading a csv file with entries like so:

```
4,[the mentalist, dodgeball, meet the fockers]
5,[godfather, the heat, friends]
...
```

I read this python using the csv module, and normally Id do:

```
import ast
x=ast.literal_eval(row[1])
```

However this obviously fails because the list entries are not quoted.

How do I get around this problem? :(

Comment: you should simply stop using csv as a format here.

Comment: this is the case when the way of writing into the input file should be fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This "format" is really unlucky to parse (e.g. what if the name of the movie contains `,`? then I don't know how to parse that file).

Your best bet is to fix it in the source (how the file is generated).

If you cannot fix how the file is generated you can try:

```py
with open("data.csv", "r") as f_in:
    for line in map(str.strip, f_in):
        if not line:
            continue
        row = line.split(",", maxsplit=1)
        if "[" in row[1]:
            row[1] = row[1].strip("[]").split(", ")
        print(row)
```

Prints:

```
['col1', 'col2']
['4', ['the mentalist', 'dodgeball', 'meet the fockers']]
['5', ['godfather', 'the heat', 'friends']]
```

---

The `data.csv` contains:

```
col1,col2
4,[the mentalist, dodgeball, meet the fockers]
5,[godfather, the heat, friends]
```

Comment: `row[1].strip("[]").split(", ")` this solves it for me using csv reader :)